# Django DoesNotExist Best Practices

Tags: python, django

There's a few questions about this but none with a definitive answer. What's the best way to handle something like:

```
user = Users.objects.get(id=1)
post = Posts.objects.get(id=1)
```

Is it to use `Users.objects.filter()[0]` instead and check for None?

Is it to surround the whole thing in a try/catch and return custom responses depending on which isn't found? That seems tedious if we're looking up more than 1-2 things.

Comment: As explained in duplicate, it depends what you want to do if it doesn't exist

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, accessing the first item in the QuerySet via index:

```
Users.objects.filter()[0]
```

would throw an `IndexError` if there is no object at position 0, not a `DoesNotExist` exception.

When checking for a non-existent object, I opt for:

```
try:
    User.objects.get(pk=1)
except User.DoesNotExist:
    # do something else

try:
    Post.objects.get(pk=1)
except Post.DoesNotExist:
    # do something else
```

However, you could do:

```
user = User.objects.filter(pk=1).first()
post = Post.objects.filter(pk=1).first()

if not all([user, post]):
    # do something else
```

`.first()` returns `None` if no object is found. Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#first

or also:

```
user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=1)
```

Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404

Which methodology you choose largely depends on your specific use case.

Comment: ^^^ Quality concise breakdown. A+.